# Initialize std::array with a random size

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std, gnu

I have two macros:

```
#define length(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
#define randRange(x,y) x + ( std::rand() % ( y - x + 1 ) )
```

I Can do this:

```
int data[] = {2, 3, 34, 10, 3, 12, 30 };
const int arr_length = length(data);
std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;
```

I Can initialize with a constant:

```
const int arr_length = 500;
std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;
```

But I can't initialize an std::array with my rand function:

```
float a = randRange(2, 200);
const int arr_length = (int)a;
std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;

float a = randRange(2, 200);
int counter = 0;
for(int i =0; i < a; i++){
    counter++;
}
const int arr_length = counter;
std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;

float a = randRange(2, 200);
const int arr_length = static_cast<int>(a);
```

***None of these work.***

I've tried all sorts of variables like *size_t* and *unsigned ints*, *constants*, *pointers* etc. I always get this error message

Error msg I always receive:    float a = randRange(2, 200);
    const int arr_length = static_cast(a);

```
/home/martin/Documents/github/on-line-mean-calculation/tests/test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void algorithmTest_TestAlgorithmRandomArray_Test::TestBody()’:
/home/martin/Documents/github/on-line-mean-calculation/tests/test.cpp:87:20: error: the value of ‘arr_length’ is not usable in a constant expression
     std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;
                    ^
/home/martin/Documents/github/on-line-mean-calculation/tests/test.cpp:76:15: note: ‘arr_length’ was not initialized with a constant expression
     const int arr_length = static_cast<int>(a);
               ^
/home/martin/Documents/github/on-line-mean-calculation/tests/test.cpp:87:30: error: the value of ‘arr_length’ is not usable in a constant expression
     std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;
                              ^
/home/martin/Documents/github/on-line-mean-calculation/tests/test.cpp:76:15: note: ‘arr_length’ was not initialized with a constant expression
     const int arr_length = static_cast<int>(a);
               ^
/home/martin/Documents/github/on-line-mean-calculation/tests/test.cpp:87:30: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’ 
     std::array<int,arr_length> data_std_array;
```

***How can I initialize and std array with a random length in range?***

Comment: The short answer: you can't. `std::array`'s size is a ***compile time*** constant. Pretty sure it's very difficult to derive a compile-time constant from some random value that's determined at run-time.

Comment: They said I could do anything in C++...

Comment: Yeah, you definitely can make a compile-time pseudo-random number generator (I challenge you to replicate std::mt19937 :P), seed it with e.g. `__TIME__` and get the value from it.

Comment: @Hartun • anything, except can't do not-C++ in C++.  However, what you could do is have the random number written to a text file that is used to recompile the application with the random value and then execute the new application from the old application.

Comment: @Eljay I was thinking about that

Comment: Why do you want a compile-time size? Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: "They said I could do anything in C++..." Try unassisted human flight. But if we restrict the bounds to the realm of programming, you can do anything. Just not this way.

Comment: @user4581301 There is a chance feeding `*(int*)0=0;` to OP's compiler will send him flying by the power of nasal demons. ._.

Comment: Nah. As of C++666 that one summons C'thulhu.

Comment: `arr_length ` must have a constant value... otherwise won't work...

Comment: Compile time size - `std::array`, run time size - `std::vector`.

Comment: By the way, **you should avoid macros in C++**. In the above example, there are absolutely no reason do define `length` or `randRange` as a macro. Macros are dangerous. For example the first macro will give wrong result when you accidently pass a pointer and the second one would give wrong result if you pass a complex expression. **Why write dangerous code, when one can write safe code in C++.** This does not make much sense.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Somebody already made a `__TIME__`-based RNG (using a PCG generator, which is supposed to have some nicer properties than MT). https://youtu.be/rpn_5Mrrxf8

Comment: By the way, in C++17, there is `std::size` that should be used instead. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size.

Comment: @DanielH compile-time that sounds like some voodoo applicable in systems that recompile themselves..

Answer (score 3):

No; array's length must be a compile time constant, and there are no compile time random number engines in `std` C++ library.

If you want a runtime determined contiguous buffer of data, use `std::vector`.  That it what it is for, and what it does.

If you want a non-`std` random number compile-time constant, choose 4.  [I rolled it using a fair die.](https://xkcd.com/221/)

In theory you could use macros that encode the compile time of your code and write a compile time pseudo-random number generator based on that.  Or you could use continuation passing style and templated code with a bound to compile some large number K of programs and choose which one to execute at runtime.  But all of these are quite frankly bad ideas.

Heck, you could make your C++ program print a C++ program to a file, include a C++ compiler in your program, link against the output of the program you print dynamically, and run that code.

Comment: Can I make a vector ... and convert it to a std::array ?

Comment: @hartun Yes, but not in the way I think you are asking.

Comment: @Yakk I would go with "no", in the general case. Once the program is compiled only certain instantiations of `std::array` are actually in the source code. At that point it is impossible to make one for a size that doesn't exist without shelling out to the compiler and dynamically loading a new module or something equally bad.

Comment: @DanielH "No" except if you do insane things is the same as "Yes" but not in the way you are asking.  ;)  I can think of a bunch of ways to do it with vary in evil from compiling code and dynamically loading it, hacking binaries, to creating N template versions of your code and dispatching to which one at run time.  Hence "Yes".  Almost anything can be done.  This is the Turing Tar Pit.

Answer (score 3):

A [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) has a *compile-time* size. That means that, no matter what you do with it, every time you run the program, it will create an array with the same number of elements. If that's not what you want, you should look into [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which can change size at *run-time*, so it can be different every time you run the program.

Either way, you shouldn't create macros unless they are necessary. Sometimes they are, but usually (including in these cases), they cause more problems than they solve and you should use functions instead. Both your `length` and `randRange` macros are better implemented as functions, and `length` already exists as [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

## Run-Time Random Number Generation

If you want run-time random numbers, which are what people usually want when talking about randomness, you should use the [C++ randomness library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), not the [`rand` function inherited from C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand). However, it can be difficult to use unless you know a lot more than most programmers want to bother learning about random numbers; I'd recommend using some library based on it that's easier to use, like [the randutils library](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/ease-of-use-without-loss-of-power.html).

## Compile-Time Random Number Generation

If, for some reason, you want to generate a random number at compile time, so that every time you run the program you get the same number but if you recompile you get a different one, that is possible in C++11 and later. There's [a C++ Weekly video about this topic](https://youtu.be/rpn_5Mrrxf8), and other examples you can find online.